# how to graph the fixed terms of mined model in R?

Tags: graph, lme4, mixed-models

I am fitting mixed model in R. My model is:

```
model <- lmer(provision_rate~breeding_type+nestling_age+time+sex:nestling_age)+(1|nest)+(1|individual), data = provision)
```

Sex is the sex of parent. I want to graph the relation between the interaction term (sex:nestling_age) and provision_rate. I don't know how to add the predicted line according to model with other parameters set to their mean values to scatter figure in R?

Comment: what have you tried? Also, can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Dummy data is okay.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem is to use the data manipulation tools in the `merTools` package in order to create a data.frame that simulates the relationship you want to explore. Here is an example using the `VerbAgg` data from the `lme4` package, but you should be able to easily adopt it to your data and model.

```
data(VerbAgg)
fmVA <- glmer(r2 ~ (Anger + Gender + btype + situ)^2 +
       (1|id) + (1|item), family = binomial, 
       data = VerbAgg)
```

We prep the data using the `draw` function in `merTools`. Here we 
draw the average observation from the model frame. We then `wiggle` the 
data by expanding the dataframe to include the same observation repeated 
but with different values of the variable specified by the `var` 
parameter. Here, we expand the dataset to all values of `btype`, `situ`, 
and `Anger` subsequently.

```
# Select the average case
newData <- draw(fmVA, type = "average")
newData <- wiggle(newData, var = "btype", values = unique(VerbAgg$btype))
newData <- wiggle(newData, var = "situ", values = unique(VerbAgg$situ))
newData <- wiggle(newData, var = "Anger", values = unique(VerbAgg$Anger))

head(newData, 10)

   r2 Anger Gender btype  situ id        item
1   N    20      F curse other  5 S3WantCurse
2   N    20      F scold other  5 S3WantCurse
3   N    20      F shout other  5 S3WantCurse
4   N    20      F curse  self  5 S3WantCurse
5   N    20      F scold  self  5 S3WantCurse
6   N    20      F shout  self  5 S3WantCurse
7   N    11      F curse other  5 S3WantCurse
8   N    11      F scold other  5 S3WantCurse
9   N    11      F shout other  5 S3WantCurse
10  N    11      F curse  self  5 S3WantCurse
```

In the next step we simply pass this new dataset to `predictInterval` in order to generate predictions for these counterfactuals and we bind these predictions to the original data.

```
plotdf <- predictInterval(fmVA, newdata = newData, type = "probability", 
        stat = "median", n.sims = 1000)
plotdf <- cbind(plotdf, newData)
```

Then we plot the predicted values against the continuous variable, `Anger`, 
and facet and group on the two categorical variables `situ` and `btype` 
respectively.

```
ggplot(plotdf, aes(y = fit, x = Anger, color = btype, group = btype)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(aes(color = btype), method = "lm") + 
  facet_wrap(~situ) + theme_bw() +
  labs(y = "Predicted Probability")
```

Which produces the following plot of fitted values:

[image]